# Jquery UI droppable sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I hope this is not a duplicate. I am trying to get the sortable work with droppable. In the jsfiddle I can move the widgets from "Available Widgets" to "Active Widgets" and vice versa but I want the widgets to be sortable under active widgets with a callback that tells me which widget is at number one and which one is at number two.

Basically looking to have capability to arrange widget order under active widgets and save the position index of it.

Can you please advise how can I achieve this?

JSFidder for the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/LLaMF/

```
<div id="jtwidgets" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default"        style="width:100%;height:300px; background:#f9f9f9">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Active Widgets</h4>
</div>

<ul id="widgetShow" class="widgetShow ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix"     style="width:100%;height:200px;; background:#f9f9f9">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">Available Widgets</h4>
    <li id="one" class="i-widget-content ui-corner-tr">Widget1</li>
    <li id="two" class="i-widget-content ui-corner-tr">Widget2</li>
    <li id="three" class="i-widget-content ui-corner-tr">Widget3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). That works great with droppable.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Can you please elaborate,  I am already using draggable. The jsfiddle has the example.

Comment: sortable works well on its own. draggable and droppable work well together. I tried combining draggable or droppable with sortable, but that didn't work very well. Try using only sortable or only draggable and droppable.